# Wrapping ID's in CSS Classes?

Tags: css

I am relatively new to CSS and wondering whether its possible to "Wrap" ID's so you don't have to repeat them over and over ?

i.e.

```
#home
{
some stuff
}

#home .header {
some stuff
}

#home .sub_header {
some stuff
}
```

Is it possible to "wrap" the .header and .sub_header so I don't have to keep repeating #home all the time ? i.e. something like this so the ID can collectively wrap the classes?

```
#home
{
some stuff
}

@#home [

.header {
some stuff
}

.sub_header {
some stuff
}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, great first question!

Comment: :) thx, i'm actually not all that new to CSS but thought it might be a *silly* first question :P

Comment: It *should* be possible, but unfortunately it's not. Hierarchical CSS would be sweet indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent question! This is not possible with native CSS I'm afraid. There are no real short cuts to take.

If you work with a lot of CSS, there are pre-compilers that allow you to use enhanced notation, and convert it into CSS on the fly.

There's for example

- [**xCSS**](http://xcss.antpaw.org/) it can [**nest child elements**](http://xcss.antpaw.org/docs/syntax/children).
- Then there's [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/), it's written in Ruby so you need that installed (as far as I understand, I haven't used it myself yet) but it's perfectly suitable for editing CSS in any environment. Check the "**nested rules**" section on the front page.

If you are just getting started with CSS, you may want to stick with the native notation first, though. But the moment it gets really tedious, those tools are a great help.

Comment: .less (dot-less) is another one, dotlesscss.com. I believe this is a port of the Ruby LESS library. Works very well.

Comment: hey great :) im using asp.net mvc so ill check it!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible in just CSS, you can however achieve this using CSS generators such as [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) which have their own syntax and have features like nesting and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Another great **CSS framework** is **[CSS Scaffold](http://github.com/anthonyshort/csscaffold)**

CSS Scaffold is powered by PHP, is easy to use

- allows **deep selector nesting**
- **constants**
- custom **mixins** (reusable pieces of css code)
- implements a grid creation framework
- **caching** of already parsed css files for production (**+minify**)

If you are not coding a big site, I would still recommend **plain css**

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP, consider using lessphp (http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/), or http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfLessPhpPlugin for symfony