# How to have constants in Flex CSS files

Tags: css, apache-flex

How can I have a constant in a Flex application which I could apply at several places in a Flex CSS file? For example I may have a background color which is the same in several UI components and then I would like to have this color set in only one place and reused in all style clauses. Something like ...

```
public static const myColor = "#00FF00"

...

component1 
{
  backgroundColor: myColor
}

component2 {
  backgroundColor: myColor
}
```

Comment: I don't know whehther a Flex CSS file is somehow embedded into the project. If it's a normal text file, and nothing comes up here, check out xCSS and LESS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279394/wrapping-ids-in-css-classes/2279406#2279406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I use.  Check out the [StylesheetMixin class on Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/28584/flex-stylesheet-mixin--custom-properties-in-css/).

This is what it looks like in use:

**ColorPalette**

```
package
{
    // only make bindable if you want to use in skins
    // for example like color="{ColorPalette.crazyColor}"
    [Bindable]
    /**
     *  This class holds all of your global colors to apply to skins.
     */
    public class ColorPalette
    {
        // "var", not "const", so you can optionally change them at runtime
        public static var crazyColor:uint = 0xff0000;
        public static const applicationAccent:uint = 0x1a01dd;
    }   
}
```

**Stylesheet**

```
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace tlf "library://ns.adobe.com/flashx/textLayout";

mx|Panel
{
    color: crazyColor;
    backgroundColor: applicationAccent;
}
mx|Button
{
    color: crazyColor;
    backgroundColor: applicationAccent;
}
```

Flex 3 equivalent:

```
Panel
{
    color: crazyColor;
    backgroundColor: applicationAccent;
}
Button
{
    color: crazyColor;
    backgroundColor: applicationAccent;
}
```

**Sample Application**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:local="*">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import ColorPalette;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <!-- simple css -->
    <mx:Style source="main.css"/>

    <!-- stylesheet palette -->
    <local:StylesheetMixin palettes="{[ColorPalette]}"/>

    <!-- sample container -->
    <mx:Panel id="panel" width="100%" height="100%" title="Stylesheet Palettes!">
        <mx:Button label="Button"/>
    </mx:Panel>

</mx:Application>
```

I have palettes for:

- Colors
- Assets
- Effects
- Layout

Works with Flex 3 and 4.

Comment: Nice! I can't wait to hook this up.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried this approach and it works in Flex 3 environment as you mentioned.
BTW I found this article which provides similar solution: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Another_way_for_runtime_styling-16300.html
Any pros and cons between the two approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, wouldn't that be nice? There's no way we have found to do this natively. We've tried commenting around colors, like:

```
background-color:/**mainBGColor**/#FFFFFF/*mainBGColor*/;
```

and then doing GREP substitutions, but this hasn't been very satisfactory.

A very good question. Adobe, are you listening?

Comment: A kind of "native" way to do it - http://www.robertbak.com/wordpress/2011/10/using-constants-in-flex-css-with-compile-time-error-checking/